# How to get Id after POST using fetch in react and show it in the alert box

Tags: reactjs, post, fetch

I'm  posting conatct us from data in db using fetch but I want show the "Id" of data inserted in the alert box but I don't know how to put into the alert box.

```
export const postFeedback = (firstname, lastname, telnum, email, agree, contactType, message) => (dispatch) => {
    const Feedback = {
        firstname: firstname,
        lastname: lastname,
        telnum: telnum,
        email: email,
        agree: agree,
        contactType: contactType,
        message: message
    }
    //Feedback.date = new Date().toISOString();
    //Feedback.id = new id().toISOString();
    return fetch(baseUrl + 'feedback', {
        method: 'POST',
        body: JSON.stringify(Feedback),
        headers: {
            'Content-Type': 'application/json'
        },
        credentials: 'same-origin'
    })
        .then(response => {
            if (response.ok) {
                return response;
            }
            else {
                var error = new Error('Error' + response.status + ': ' + response.statusText);
                error.response = response;
                throw error;
            }

        },
            error => {
                var errmess = new Error(error.message);
                throw errmess;
            })
        .then(response => response.json())
        .then(alert('Your data  posted\n: ' + JSON.stringify(Feedback) ))
        .catch(error => {
            console.log('Error while posting data', error.message);
            alert('Error while posting data: \nError' + error.message);
        });

}
```

See the screenshot after the message I want to insert Id from the database but don't know how to proceed with this.

[image]

Here I'm attaching the  response.json() and it is returning the id

[image]

Comment: Can you print response.json() and add it to your question? i think the id is returned in the response body

Comment: Yes..It is returning Id and I have updated the screenshot

Answer (score 0):

Update postFeedback function to this

```
export const postFeedback = (firstname, lastname, telnum, email, agree, contactType, message) => (dispatch) => {
const Feedback = {
    firstname: firstname,
    lastname: lastname,
    telnum: telnum,
    email: email,
    agree: agree,
    contactType: contactType,
    message: message
}
//Feedback.date = new Date().toISOString();
//Feedback.id = new id().toISOString();
return fetch(baseUrl + 'feedback', {
    method: 'POST',
    body: JSON.stringify(Feedback),
    headers: {
        'Content-Type': 'application/json'
    },
    credentials: 'same-origin'
})
    .then(response => {
        if (response.ok) {
            return response;
        }
        else {
            var error = new Error('Error' + response.status + ': ' + response.statusText);
            error.response = response;
            throw error;
        }

    },
        error => {
            var errmess = new Error(error.message);
            throw errmess;
        })
    .then(response => response.json())
    .then((res)=>alert('Your data  posted\n: ' + res.id ))
    .catch(error => {
        console.log('Error while posting data', error.message);
        alert('Error while posting data: \nError' + error.message);
    });
```

}

Answer (score 0):

As you have the id from the response and you are already converting it to json ,you can add the id like this:

```
 .then((response)=>alert('Your data  posted\n: ' + response.id ))
```

Complete code:

```
export const postFeedback = (firstname, lastname, telnum, email, agree, contactType, message) => (dispatch) => {
    const Feedback = {
        firstname: firstname,
        lastname: lastname,
        telnum: telnum,
        email: email,
        agree: agree,
        contactType: contactType,
        message: message
    }
    //Feedback.date = new Date().toISOString();
    //Feedback.id = new id().toISOString();
    return fetch(baseUrl + 'feedback', {
        method: 'POST',
        body: JSON.stringify(Feedback),
        headers: {
            'Content-Type': 'application/json'
        },
        credentials: 'same-origin'
    })
        .then(response => {
            if (response.ok) {
                return response;
            }
            else {
                var error = new Error('Error' + response.status + ': ' + response.statusText);
                error.response = response;
                throw error;
            }

        },
            error => {
                var errmess = new Error(error.message);
                throw errmess;
            })
        .then(response => response.json())
        .then((response)=>alert('Your data  posted\n: ' + response.id ))
        .catch(error => {
            console.log('Error while posting data', error.message);
            alert('Error while posting data: \nError' + error.message);
        });

}
```